# Could not proxy reques

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/profile/all from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000. [1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET)

Hi I was wondering if anyone knows the solution to this problem. The application was working just fine yesterday, but today it started raising this error up. Please I desperately need help. I have to finish this project before the 5th of February.

//package.json(Node)

```
{
  "name": "devconnector",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Social network for developers",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\""
  },
  "author": "Brad Traversy",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.12",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^9.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3"
  }
}
```

//package.json(React)

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-html-table-to-excel": "^2.0.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "reactstrap": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly are you using socket in project ??

Comment: No @MohitKumarBordia

Comment: I don't know much regarding this because I am very new regarding MERN stack and according to the error that I still get is this Could not proxy request /sockjs-node/030/helcjqks/websocket